# Are jinns and angels "creatures" too?

Tags: tafseer, jinn, malaikah, surat-al-anam

> [And there is no creature on [or within] the earth or bird that flies with its wings except [that they are] communities like you. We have not neglected in the Register a thing. Then unto their Lord they will be gathered.](http://tanzil.net/#6:38) [6:38]

Does the *"creature"* mentioned above include the both jinns and angels or either?

Taking *"creature"* literally i.e.:

> [something created either animate or inanimate: as ...c: a being of anomalous or uncertain aspect or nature](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/creature)

then I think they would. But would that be in agreement with the Islamic perspective?

Comment: please note the word used in this verse is دابه which is different of Arabic word for creature (مخلوق). translation is not important. for example another translator has translated دابه to: crawling creature. Arabic lexicons define Arabic words better.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the Arabic text of the verse you will find Allah has used the world "دابة" and not "مخلوق" and the difference is that Makhluq is as you wrote for literal meaning of creature, anything created and more precisely being created, but Daabbah denote only a category among all the creatures, that is, those that move, seemingly those that are animate!

The Jinns can be included even under the title "you" in "communities like you". The reason for that is the fact that Quran is the guidance book for both human being and Jinns. See Surah Ar-Rahman to see how many times Allah asks the two groups of Humans and Jinns if they deny any of the blessings of Allah: "فَبِأَيِّ آلَاءِ رَ‌بِّكُمَا تُكَذِّبَانِ". However, if Jinns society and ours are similar there is nothing that will prevent you from also interpreting "you" as only human and consider Jinns as in described by moving species or flying species having the same communities as ours.

Also I don't see any problem in considering also angels as being included in these categories. Let me here insist again that I am not a scholar, but my small amount of studies of Quran, Tafseer and Hadeeth do not prevent me from assuming such. It sounds quite reasonable indeed. For example we know both Jinns and angels of all different kinds have communities, all will die before the Day and all will arise at the resurrection. How the angels will die and how everything will arise for the Day are available in Shia Ahadeeth and all were reasonable as far as I could say.

Hope I have not misunderstood your question entirely :)

Comment: Good answer. I actually asked this question to build upon it another question, which you touched in this answer. i.e. will angel have a Day of Judgment? Do they have a shajaray and community of their own?

Answer (score 1):

Jinns and angels exist and they are creatures, but they have different nature from human being. Our nature is mud, angel's nature is light and jinn's fire.

Plus, they live in different worlds. Human being's live in Alame Shohud but angels exist in Alame Malakut, that's why we can't see them.

At the end, they are creature but we can't see them based on their different world and nature.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they are also "Creature" too.

First thing to remember is that ALLAH is AL-GANIYU & AL-KHALIQU, ALLAH is independent & creator of all things.

No any Angel or Jinn are independent, they are all depend on ALLAH.
Even to perform whatever qualities Jinns & Angel have they also need help of ALLAH to perform their work.