# Is it true that the angel of death will get itself?

Tags: death, malaikah

After some research, I've found that all the angels will die before the day of judgement, and will rise on ressurection ( [answer of owari](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10551/are-jinns-and-angels-creatures-too) ).

I've also heard that the angel of death will get itself, and that only god will remain.

Are there any verses from the Quran or ahadith from the sunna that validate this point?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I've edited the question as there are no evidences that it is named Azrael, but it is only one angel (the eleventh verse of Surat 
As-Sajdah : https://quran.com/32)

Comment: You know, I heard the same thing too. I cannot remember wear exactly (was on youtube by a top scholar I believe). I think he will be the last angel standing and Allah will ask him to die/be laid to rest

Comment: Even i have heard such a thing on YouTube on the channel MercifulServant

Comment: Those are nothing but speculations. Youtube song ? some entertainment youtube channel ? Come on. Know your sources.

Comment: @cerberus23 Yes, I know, that's why I am looking for a relevant source.

Comment: If you want my opinion, I'd recommend researching the root meaning of "Angel" " Malak " i.e the controller. And search their occurence in the Quran. I'm saying this because the mainstream perception of angels is very likely to be biased therefore  "Angels" that everyone speak of are much like the fairy tales you hear from older mythologies.

Comment: @cerberus23 read http://legacy.quran.com/4/136, read http://legacy.quran.com/35/1, read http://legacy.quran.com/42/5 and many other verses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Who takes our lives?**

In Quran we find three different and apparently contradictory statements:

- One saying it is **the** angel of death in surat as-sajdah [32:11](http://legacy.quran.com/32/11) ... note that this verse can be understood that for each one of us there's such an entrusted angel. However most tafsirs i consulted say it is one angel.
- An other saying that those are many angels like in surat an-Nisa' [4:97](http://legacy.quran.com/4/97), surat al-An'aam [6:61](http://legacy.quran.com/6/61) and surat Muhammad [47:27](http://legacy.quran.com/47/27).
- And a third statement saying it is Allah in surat az-Zumar [39:42](http://legacy.quran.com/39/42).

these differences can be explained as follows assuming there's one angel of death we can conclude from the other verses that this angel only acts by Allah's order so it is by his order that he takes a life (ruh or rooh) and on the other hand this angel might have helpers among angels, as he as the angel of death is the angel that is ordered to receive a rooh once the person has died. This would also be an explication if we take into account my note that every person might have an angel which is entrusted to take the rooh/soul, but Allah knows best!

**Do angels die?**

According to Quran everything dies or has an end expect Allah as you may read in surat al-Qasas [28:88](http://legacy.quran.com/28/88) or ar-Rahman [57:26-27](http://legacy.quran.com/55/26-27). Note that the later verse can't be used as a proof for the malaika as it quotes those creatures that are "on Earth".

There's a munkar hadith (this means a rejected hadith) which you may read in the Arabic original [here](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/98757) which is partly also quoted in tafsir [at-Tabari](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=50&surano=39&ayano=68) of verse [39:68](http://legacy.quran.com/39/68) which describes the end of the world and the day of resurrection or as al-Maududi says:

> This is a figurative way of describing the complete control and authority of Allah over the earth and heavens. Just as a man encloses a small ball in the hollow of his hand with perfect ease, or a person rolls up an handkerchief in his hand without any difficulty, so will All men (who fail to conceive the greatness and glory of Allah) sec with their own eyes, on the Day of Resurrection, that the earth and the heavens arc like an ordinary ball and a small scroll in the hand of Allah. ...

Note that according to this munkar hadith the angel of death will take the lives of the few angels who still have not yet died until there's only him and Allah and than Allah will say to him: die and he would die.

Also note that ibn Hazm and some other scholars say that angels won't die based on this verse of surat az-Zumar 39:68 as it clearly says.

> And the Horn will be blown, and whoever is in the heavens and whoever is on the earth will fall dead **except whom Allah wills**. ...

Mufassireen like at-Tabari concluded that angels are among those who will stay alive, so there might be creatures which may stay alive! This finds also some support in surat al-A'raaf [7:20](http://legacy.quran.com/7/20):

> He said, "Your Lord did not forbid you this tree except that you **become angels** or become of the immortal."

which may support the view that angels wouldn't die! An objection to this could be the fact that angels have been quoted separately from the immortal which may mean that they are not among the immortal creatures.

Finally: There's no reliable hadith saying that the angel of death will get itself (or himself). And there's no clear Quranic verse which may even support the idea that angels would die at all, but there are interpretation of verses from which one could conclude this and others which oppose this idea.

See also [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/96306).

Answer (score -1):

Angels and souls do not die , while Souls do get to taste death ,
I do not know from where you found this , if you accept angels can die then you will have no choice but to accept the christian belief that God died on the cross.

---

Once a Christian pastor used to visit a arab muslim sheik in the deserts and use to try frequently to convince him to accept Christianity by accepting that Christ the son of God and God himself manifested died on the cross for the sins of men.

As the evangelist became a daily nuisance to Sheik came up with a plan and told his servant the next time the evangelist comes he (The Servant) should come and whisper into the sheik's ears  .

The next morning the The evangelist visited as usual , and the servant came hurriedly and whispered into his master's ears ,and soon after that The Sheik broke down and cried howling, the evangelist all confused and some what concerned inquired from the Sheik what was the grief , The Sheik replied Oh Gabriel (Jibril) has died , for this the Evangelist responded angrily , you fool how can angels die? and the Sheik replied , oh you fool then how can you expect me to believe that God died . 
You need to be careful what you read and accept online, there is a huge attempt to divert the iman of Muslims ,please stick to the quran as much as possible. 
(Matching wits )